# Using WGET to retrieve information from PLC - Error 400 Bad Request

Tags: wget, plc, bad-request, s7-1200, tia-portal

I'm attempting to use the wget program to retrieve and save a list of data from my Siemens S7-1200 PLC. Using a batch file I had written I was able drill down the folder path to my wget.exe file. Upon running the wget executable I get the error message seen in the attached screenshot, labeled "Command Prompt Screenshot".

The command prompt shows me that I've "connected" and I know the username and password are correct because I can log into the PLC using my web browser. It's for those reasons I'm stumped on what the problem is.

Has anyone seen this before or can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image: Command Prompt Screenshot]

Comment: What kind of header info do you have in wget.ini? Does the PLC only allow https connections? I'd recommend starting wireshark, connect to the PLC's webpage using your normal browser, and then looking at wireshark's capture. You might need to modify the browser agent or post data to get it to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response Ken. I was actually able to get it working with the assistance of the Siemens technical support. Apparently my computer didn't like the way I was trying to pass it the username and password login credentials. Through Siemens TIA Portal software I was able remove the login restrictions, allowing all users access to reading data off the PLC and it works now. I've attached a copy of the exact batch file I used. Also, to make sure I'm adding as much detail as possible, I have the batch file and the wget.exe file saved to a folder on my c:\ drive. [Functional wget batch file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2iTc.png)